# React-Native Youtube player using pods?

Tags: ios, youtube, react-native

Any idea how to install [this](http://www.reactnative.com/a-youtube-component-for-react-native/) using pods ? What is the pod specification for installing the Youtube package ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this below line in your podfile,

```
pod "youtube-ios-player-helper", "~> 0.1.4"
```

After installing in your project and opening the workspace, to use the library:

1. Drag a `UIView` the desired size of your player onto your `Storyboard`.
2. Change the `UIView's` class in the Identity Inspector tab to `YTPlayerView`
3. Import `"YTPlayerView.h"` in your ViewController.
4. Add the following property to your ViewController's header file

`@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet YTPlayerView *playerView;`

5. Load the video into the player in your controller's code with the following code

`[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"M7lc1UVf-VE"];`  // The YouTube video ID

6. Run your code!

Hope this helped you!!